How to measure Flask API response time and record them in logs?
I have a log system for my flask API
import logging

def setup_logger(logp=None, debug=False):
    log_level = logging.DEBUG if debug else logging.INFO
    form = "[%(asctime)s][%(name)s][%(levelname)s][%(filename)s] %(message)s"
    datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"
    logging.basicConfig(level=log_level, format=form, datefmt=datefmt)
    if logp is not None:
        fhandler = logging.StreamHandler(open(logp, 'a'))
        fhandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(form, datefmt))
        logging.root.addHandler(fhandler)


logger = logging.getLogger("MY_APP")
setup_logger()
logger.debug(f"Import {__file__}")

And the logs look like:
[2024-04-19-04:20:02][werkzeug][INFO][_internal.py] 172.23.0.2 - - [19/Apr/2024 04:20:02] "GET /available/space HTTP/1.1" 200 -

However, I want to measure and record my flask API response time and add them to logs also, like 0.45 s, in order to see which API handler is slow.
The expecting behavior is like this:
[2024-04-19-04:20:02][werkzeug][INFO][_internal.py][0.45 s] 172.23.0.2 - - [19/Apr/2024 04:20:02] "GET /available/space HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Is there any method to conduct that? Thanks

Maybe a decorator on your api methods would work for this?

@Kraigolas Thank you for your suggestion. However, if I follow this approach, I'll have to add a decorator to each API method, and I have hundreds of API methods. It would become very cluttered. Is there a more elegant solution you could suggest?

You can use before_request and after_request to effect this on all routes. We'll make use of the g to store the start time of the request, and you can get the function name from request.endpoint.
I haven't set up logging itself for this example, but it should be trivial to inject your own logging mechanism in, in place of print().
from flask import Flask, g, request
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def log_route_start():
    g.start_time = time.time()
    
@app.after_request
def log_route_end(response):
    route = request.endpoint
    print(f"{route} ended after {time.time() - g.pop('start_time', None)}")
    return response

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    time.sleep(1)
    return "Hello"

@app.route('/test2', methods=['GET'])
def test2():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return "Bye"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


Thank you for providing great solution in elegant way, but I just noticed you leverage flask.g.start_time in your solution, and I wanna know what else should we do on top of that to avoid being messed-up when we have concurrent requests coming?

@stevezkw nothing; g is context-bound to the individual requests

Awesome! Thank you for providing helpful explanation to help me understand it better. let me check it out, cheers

Just keep your updated, your solution works on my side and plays an key role in my app.
Thank you for your help!
But I am still figuring out how to integrate the log you created with my existing logging mechanism
So we can merge them into one, anyway, you did a great job!
